# Multiple usernames in FTP login

Tags: ftp

I have script which will do ftp transfer to one server. See the code below

```
ftp -n -i 192.9.210.13
user ops@zeusftp pwd1@pwd2
bin
//Some Transfers here
bye
```

My question is in the server 192.9.210.13 we have only zeusftp id. We don't have any id ops in both source and destination servers. When I use only zeusftp id it's not connecting to the server. What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 0):

We found the meaning of this. In the ftp above the first username ops and password pwd1 is for   domain controller/network login details. The next one is for the actual server. While network migration we faced this issue. Removing the first id and password it worked fine.